# Is there a whitespace character I missed while trying to output an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, output

The code runs well, but I am having trouble in displaying the ArrayList in a method. I tried looking for any whitespace characters I may have missed.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int choice = 0;
    String input ="";
    do{
        
        ArrayList<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
        
        System.out.println("Choose an option: ");
        System.out.println("1. Add a fruit\n2. Delete a fruit");
        System.out.println("3. Display fruits\n4. Exit");
        
        choice = scan.nextInt();
        
        if(choice == 1)
        {
          input = addFruit(input);
          fruits.add(input);
        }
        else if(choice == 2)
        {
            input = deleteFruit(input);
            fruits.remove(input);
            System.out.println(input + " deleted from the list");
        }
        else if(choice == 3)
        {
           displayFruit(fruits); 
        }
    }while(choice !=4);
    
    System.out.println("Exiting the program. Goodbye!");
  }
public static void displayFruit(ArrayList<String> f)
{
    for(int i=0;i<f.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Here is the list: " + f.get(i));
    }
}
public static String addFruit(String i)
{
    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the fruit: ");
    i = scan.nextLine();
    return i;
}
public static String deleteFruit(String i)
{
    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the fruit you want to delete: ");
    i = scan.nextLine();
    return i;
}
}
```

I have tried rewriting the output loop for displayFruit, but to no avail.

Comment: Move the ArrayList instantiation (`ArrayList<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>();`) outside the loop.

Comment: Moving the Arraylist<String> fruits outside the loop made the program work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why are you passing a `String i` to `addFruit` and `deleteFruit`? Those methods prompt for user input and ignore the provided `String` (which they wouldn't need anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are initializing the below statement inside the do-while loop, it gets initialized each time when the while loop executes

```
ArrayList<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
```

Move the above line before the while loop